# Solve Initial Value problem for a system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> > Consider $\ddot{x}=F(t)$ for a continious $F$. Write this as a two dimensional system of ODE, then make an autonomous system out of it and solve this autonomous system (it is three dimensional) for the initial value $(t_0,x_0,v_0)$!

Hello,

okay the first step is to make a two dimensional system of ODE out of it, this is
$$
\dot{x}=v, v=F(t).
$$
To make an autonomous three dimensional system of ODE out of that I set $s=t$ and then get
$$
\dot{s}=1, \dot{x}=v, \dot{v}=F(s). ~~~~(*)
$$
Now the task is to solve this for the initialvalues $(t_0,x_0,v_0)$.

Because this new system is autonomous I think it is meant that the starting time is 0. So I get for the first the solution
$$
a(t)=t+t_0.
$$
Furthermore I know that
$$
v(s)=\int_0^s F(\tau)\, d\tau=:g(s),~~~x(s)=\int_0^s v(\tau)\, d\tau)=:G(s).
$$

But I do not know how to solve the IVP for the two ODE $\dot{x}=v$ and $\dot{v}=F(s)$.

The solution says that the solution is given by

$$
\sigma(t)=t_0+t~~~(\text{thats what I already have}),\\
\xi(t)=x_0+\int_{t_0}^t\eta(s)\, ds=x_0+v_0(t-t_0)+G(t)-G(t_0)\\
\eta(t)=v_0+\int_{t_0}^t F(s)\, ds=v_0+g(t)-g(t_0).
$$

But, as said above, do not know how to reach $\xi(t)$ and $\eta(t)$.

Can you explain it to me?

Comment: I don't understand you did all the job already. $\eta$ is derived from the last formula since $F(\cdot)$, $v_0$  are given. $\zeta(t)$ is defived from $\eta$. What is the problem?

Comment: Which last formula do you mean? $\sigma$, $\eta$, and $xi$ are not given... its the solution I wrote down

Comment: For $\eta(t)$. $v_0$, $F(t)$ are given so you have $\eta(t)$, Now from $x_0$ and $\eta(t)$ you have $\zeta(t)$. What does it mean you cannot reach $\eta(t)$ and $\zeta(t)$ if you already completely defined them?

Comment: Mh, do not know how to express my problem. I do not know how to solve $\dot{x}=v, x(0)=x_0$ and $\dot{v}=F(s), v(0)=v_0$.

Comment: The formula for $\sigma(t), \xi(t), \eta(t)$ are not MY result. I only now that this are the results i have to reach...

Comment: OK I got it. you solution for $v(s),x(s)$ is UP TO constant.You should write $$ v(s)=C+\int_0^s F(s) ds$$ and choose constant equal to $v(0)=v_0$. And similarly for $x(s)$;